# Question about algebraically independence.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R=k[Y_1, \ldots, Y_m]/P$, where $k$ is a field and $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Suppose that $Y_1, \ldots, Y_m$ are algebraically independent over $k$. Let $y_1=Y_1+P, \ldots, y_m=Y_m+P$. Can we conclude that $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are algebraically independent over $k$?

I think that if $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are not algebraically independent, then there is a polynomial $f$ such that $f(y_1, \ldots, y_m)=P$ and we can conclude that $f(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m) \in P$. But it seems that we cannot conclude that $f(Y_1, \ldots, Y_m)=0$. Thank you very much.

Comment: How can you mod out by $P$ a structure that is defined in terms of $P$? Should $P$ really be a prime ideal of $k$ or $k[Y_{1}, \dots, Y_{m}]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are algebraically dependent over $k$ if and only if the prime ideal $P$ is non-zero.

As you have pointed out, take any non-zero polynomial in $P$.  The $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are, almost by definition, a root of this non-zero polynomial and hence algebraically dependent.

Conversely if $P = 0$ then $R = k[y_1, \ldots, y_m]$ is a polynomial ring and we therefore know that $y_1, \ldots, y_m$ are algebraically independent.